How to set editor background color according to the file path?
I'm using VS Code and I'm trying to set the editor.background color according to the file path of the opened document.
So far, I installed Peacock:
{
    "settings": {
        "peacock.favoriteColors": [
            {
                "name": "Flutter",
                "value": "#0C1E28FF"
            },
            {
                "name": "Server",
                "value": "#240A0AFF"
            }
        ]
    }
}


Is there a way to distinguish which open file belongs to which folder, by assigning a specific color to the editor.background key?
Note that I don't want to create different workspaces, as the various folders share same resources.

EDIT, I removed the reference to workspace as using it is troublemaking...

You can use an extension I wrote: When File
Example from the doc:
  "whenFile.change": {
    "byLanguageId": {
      "python": {
        "workbenchColor": {
          "editor.background": "#ddddff"
        }
      },
      "html": {
        "workbenchColor": {
          "editor.background": "#ddffdd"
        }
      }
    },
    "/projects/server/": {
      "workbenchColor": {
        "activityBar.background": "#509050"
      }
    },
    "/projects/client/": {
      "workbenchColor": {
        "activityBar.background": "#905080"
      }
    },
    "/.*\\.log$": {
      "workbenchColor": {
        "activityBar.background": "#acad60"
      }
    }
  }


I have a complementary question, that is to set the color of the active or inactive tabs, based on the adress of each tab file, instead of the adress of the active file.
For instead, all server tabs would be red, and all client tabs would be blue.
Would you have any hint?
Thnak you so much!

@Yako I don't think that is possible, I can't find an example on the UI doc page about tabs, you can try if creating some File Icon theme rules and using colored icons, but AFAIK these rules are on file extension or file name, not file path

Actually, I noticed that editor.background and tab.activeBackground were changed for all editors and tabs.
I'd like to set the colors considering the path of each file.
That way, it's possible to visually distinguish the opened files according to their path...

If you want to change the background color ,you can add some commands in settings.json .By doing this you can change the background color depending on the folders.Here you need to use command palette while opening the file.This will set the color according to the folder.
for example:
In settings.json
{
  "peacock.wishColor":[
   {
    "name":"myColor",
    "value":"#3CB371"
    }
   ]
}

Ctrl+shift+P then run Change Color of Active Worksapce. When you want to change the color, by selecting the myColor from list you can change the color.
As for as I know,I wrote this.If there are any mistakes please forgive me in advance.

That sounds interesting. Can you show an example of setting a specific color per path branch?
